# Transforming the expected value of $Y_i$ in binomial regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, link-function

Currently, I'm learning generalized linear regression (GLM). There is something troubling me concerning binomial regression.

In [this text](https://www.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/upm-binaries/21121_Chapter_15.pdf), in the part about the structure of a GLM, the random component is defined as a response variable $Y_i$ conditioned on the explanatory variable $X_i$. And the link function is a function that transforms the expectation of the response variable $\mu_i = E(Y_i)$.

However, according the [same document](https://www.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/upm-binaries/21121_Chapter_15.pdf) and [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144121/logistic-regression-bernoulli-vs-binomial-response-variables), in binomial regression, it seems that the linked function transforms $p_i (Y_i \sim Bi(m_i, p_i))$, instead of the mean of $Y_i$, $m_ip_i$.

And in [this post](https://timeseriesreasoning.com/contents/binomial-regression-model/#:%7E:text=we%20are%20interested%20in%20fixing%20the%20relation%20between%20the%20conditional%20expectation%20of%20the%20probability%20%CF%80%20of%20a%20single%20Bernoulli%20trial), it's also only mentioned that "we are interested in fixing the relation between the conditional expectation of the probability π of a single Bernoulli trial". In [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5139815), this is similar argument without further explanation:

> ...$Y\sim Binomial(n, \pi)$. Let $P_i = \frac{Y_i}{n_i}$ for i,...,m is a proportioni of success from m independent binomial observations, with $E(Y_i) = n_i\pi_i$ and $E(P_i) = \pi_i$....Binomial regressoin models assume that $\pi_i = F(x_i^T\beta), i=1,...,m$.

Here $F^{-1}$ is defined as the link function.

To summarize, my question is: in binomial regression, why does the link function transform  the probability/parameter ($p_i$), instead of the mean ($m_i p_i$), to the linear predictor ($x_i^T\beta$), as by the definition of link function?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144121/logistic-regression-bernoulli-vs-binomial-response-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, as for instance in chapter 7 of [MASS4](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS4/), the response in a binomial generalized linear model is taken as $Y_i = S_i/n_i$, that is, we use a *scaled binomial distribution* ($S_i$ is number successes, $n_i$ the fixed sample size). Then the expectation is $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \mu_i = p_i$.  It is just more natural to use $p_i$ as parameter than to use $n_i p_i$.

See also [Logistic Regression: Bernoulli vs. Binomial Response Variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144121/logistic-regression-bernoulli-vs-binomial-response-variables)